# Getting from random array

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

I have the following javascript

```
 var wordselection = [
{ 'word': "Pomme", "gender": "m", },
{ "word": "Banane", "gender": "f", },
{ "word": "Ananas", "gender": "m", },
{ "word": "Chat", "gender": "f", },
{ "word": "Chien", "gender": "m", },
{ "word": "Poisson", "gender": "f", },

];   

function randomword(){
var chosen = wordselection[Math.floor(Math.random()*wordselection.length)];
document.getElementById("word").innerHTML=chosen;
}
```

How can I code this so that the it only shows a random "word"  (e.g pomme, banane, ananas) or "gender"

At the moment it says [object Object] (because its wrong)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
var chosen = wordselection[Math.floor(Math.random()*wordselection.length)].word
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to select the word element from the object, intead of just selecting the whole object

http://jsfiddle.net/bhlaird/HKnb3/

```
var wordselection = [{
    'word': "Pomme",
    "gender": "m",
}, {
    "word": "Banane",
    "gender": "f",
}, {
    "word": "Ananas",
    "gender": "m",
}, {
    "word": "Chat",
    "gender": "f",
}, {
    "word": "Chien",
    "gender": "m",
}, {
    "word": "Poisson",
    "gender": "f",
},

];

function randomword() {
    var chosen = wordselection[Math.floor(Math.random() * wordselection.length)];
    document.getElementById("word").innerHTML = chosen.word;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this http://jsfiddle.net/U6k6G/

```
wordselection[Math.floor(Math.random()*wordselection.length)].word;
```

Answer (score 2):

I added a parmeter to your `randomword()` function so that you can specify which type you want to select from: word or gender.

```
function randomword(type) {
  var chosen=wordselection[Math.floor(Math.random()*wordselection.length)][type];
  document.getElementById("word").innerHTML += "<p>"+chosen+"</p>";
}

randomword('word');
randomword('gender');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AESvG/

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify if you want to show a word or a gender.

Add .word:

```
var chosen = wordselection[Math.floor(Math.random()*wordselection.length)].word;
```

or .gender

```
var chosen = wordselection[Math.floor(Math.random()*wordselection.length)].gender;
```